# update json from select issue

Tags: json, postgresql

The task is to update json-column with data, selected from another column.
This is a sample:

```
| id | size (bigint) | stats (json)      |
|____|_______________|___________________|
| 1  |      3        |{"countValue": 0}  |
```

I'm trying to solve the problem as follows:

```
with sizes as (select id, size
   from snapshot
)

UPDATE snapshot
    SET stats = jsonb_set(stats::jsonb, '{countValue}', sizes.size)
    from sizes
    where snapshot.id=sizes.id;
```

But I received the error below:

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The problem is located around size-value, which has bigint-type. When I apply update as follows:

```
SET stats = jsonb_set(stats::jsonb, '{countValue}', '3')
```

problem is not appear

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
  with sizes as (select id, size
        from snapshot
    )

 UPDATE snapshot SET stats =
     ('{"countValue":'||to_json(sizes.size)||'}')::json
     from sizes
     where snapshot.id=sizes.id;
```

Was useful: [MIGRATING TO JSON IN POSTGRESQL](https://developer.s24.com/blog/migrating-json-postgresql.html)